# Get the modified timestamp of a file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the modified timestamp of a file using just JavaScript?

I use a JSON file to fill a page by javascript and I would like to show the timestamp of that JSON file.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860219/is-it-possible-to-access-the-file-creation-time-of-an-img-src-in-javascript

Comment: Or perhaps better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7612943/2456258

Comment: @casey: Those may not actually be accurate, if you form your XHR call carefully... rubo77: Is it okay if it's the creation time *as far as the server knows*? (If not, I really don't see it other than embedding the data.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure, that would be enough

Comment: Would like a solution that pulls the timestamp from the file itself rather than server filesystem metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you're retrieving the file through true ajax (that is, through `XMLHttpRequest`), provided you configure your server to send the `Last-Modified` header when sending the data.

The fundamental thing here is that when you use `XMLHttpRequest`, you can access the response headers. So if the server sends back `Last-Modified`, you can use it:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    success: function(response) {
        display("Data is " + response.data + ", last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
    }
});
```

Just tried that on Chrome, Firefox, IE8, and IE11. Worked well (even when the data was coming from cache).

---

You've said below that you need to do this in a loop, but you keep seeing the last value of the variable. That tells me you've done something like this:

```
// **WRONG**
var list = /*...some list of URLs...*/;
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: list[index],
        success: function(response) {
            display("Data is " + response.data + ", last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
        }
    });
}
```

The problem there is that all of the `success` callbacks have an *enduring reference* to the `xhr` variable, and there is only one of them. So all the callbacks see the last value assigned to `xhr`.

This is the classic closure problem. Here's one solution:

```
var list = /*...some list of URLs...*/;
list.forEach(function(url) {
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            display("Data for " + url + " is " + response.data + ", last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
        }
    });
});
```

Since each iteration of the `forEach` callback gets its own `xhr` variable, there's no cross-talk. (You'll need to shim `forEach` on old browsers.)

---

You said below:

> I already thought about a closure problem, thats why I used an array `xhr[e]` in my loop over `e`...
>   But your example doesent help...

and linked to this code in a gist:

```
//loop over e....
nodename=arr[e];
node_json=path_to_node_json+nodename;
html +='<a href="'+node_json+'" target="_blank" id="host_'+nodename+'">data</a></td>'
    +'</tr>';
xhr[e] = $.ajax({
    url: node_json,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#host_'+nodename).append("last modified: " + xhr[e].getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
    }
});
```

That still has the classic error: Your `success` function closes over the *variable* `e`, not the value it had when the `success` function was created, and so by the time the `success` function runs, `e` has the last value assigned to it in the loop.

The `forEach` example I gave earlier fits this perfectly:

```
// (I assume `node_json`, `html`, and `path_to_node_json` are all declared
// here, outside the function.)
arr.forEach(function(nodename) {
    var xhr; // <=== Local variable in this specific call to the iteration
             // function, value isn't changed by subsequent iterations
    node_json=path_to_node_json+nodename;
    html +='<a href="'+node_json+'" target="_blank" id="host_'+nodename+'">data</a></td>'
        +'</tr>';
    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: node_json,
        success: function(response) {
            // Note: You haven't used it here, but just to emphasize: If
            // you used `node_json` here, it would have its value as of
            // the *end* of the loop, because it's not local to this
            // function. But `xhr` is local, and so it isn't changed on
            // subsequent iterations.
            $('#host_'+nodename).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work (at least on the same domain) How do I get a variable submitted from the call into the `function(response)`? If I call several of these calls in a loop I always have only the last value in the subfunction

Comment: I already thought about a closure problem, thats why I used an array `xhr[e]` in my loop over `e` and I get successfull cals to alll different urls. But your example doesent help, I have this problem: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/4a9077c65f8bdd5b652c I always only get the id for the last a href

Comment: I redefined the follof up problem here: [Submit variables into a loop of ajax calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25067809)

Comment: @rubo77: The code there still had the classic closure problem, and `forEach` fixes it. See the updated answer. But all of this is really tangential to the question you asked about finding the modified time.

Comment: I already fixed it with arr.map() here: [Pass a variable to a function from inside an ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25068606) but thanks for your help

Comment: @rubo77: `map` or `forEach`, it's the same idea: Create something *else* for the handler to close over. :-)