# Submit variables into a loop of ajax calls

Tags: javascript, closures

I use this loop to read some urls to read their modified time:

```
for (var e in arr) {
        nodename=arr[e].hostname;
        node_json="/nodes/"+nodename;
        html +='<a href="'+node_json+'" target="_blank" id="host_'+nodename+'">data</a>';
        xhr[e] = $.ajax({
            url: node_json,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#host_'+nodename).append(xhr[e].url+": last modified: " + xhr[e].getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
            }
        });

    }
```

This already works a bit, I get calls to all node-files, and in Firebug, I can see the different nodified times in the header of the calls.

But in my code I only get the last line modified with all results.

How can I call each id `#host_'+nodename` in each ajax call to add the right answer to the right position?

source of the AJAX call: [Get the modified timestamp of a file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062132/get-the-modified-timestamp-of-a-file-with-javascript/25064125?noredirect=1#25064125)

---

EDIT:

I tried this now:

```
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: node_json,
            success: (function(nn) {
                $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
            })(nodename)
        });
```

But that gives:

> ReferenceError: xhr is not defined
>   $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")...

Comment: `success` is an event handler.

Comment: @Quentin That seems to be the solution, but I cant manage to put it together for my problem

Comment: solved here: [Pass a variable to a function from inside an ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25068606)