# Pass a variable to a function from inside an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to use this loop to read some urls to read their modified time:

```
var arr = [];

//... fill arr with push

for (var e in arr) {
        nodename=arr[e].hostname;
        node_json="/nodes/"+nodename;
        html +='<a href="'+node_json+'" target="_blank" id="host_'+nodename+'">data</a>';

        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: node_json,
            success: (function(nn) {
                $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
            })(nodename)
        });
```

This already works a bit i I comment out the `success` line: I get calls to all node-files, and in Firebug, I can see the different modified times in the header of the calls.

At first I had a closure, (see [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript)) And I only got the last line modified with all results. that's why I try to put the action in a separate function.

But that gives:

> ReferenceError: xhr is not defined
>   $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")...

How do I get `xhr` into that function?

---

I aslo tried:

```
...
        xhr[e] = $.ajax({
            url: node_json,
            success: add_result_to_info(nodename, e)
        });

    }
}
// outside loop
function add_result_to_info(nn, e) {
    $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr[e].getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
}
```

*source of the AJAX call: [Get the modified timestamp of a file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062132/get-the-modified-timestamp-of-a-file-with-javascript/25064125?noredirect=1#25064125)*

Comment: your closure code is b0rked - you're not passing a function reference to `success`, but instead `undefined` - that being the (non-existent) return value of `(function(nn) ...)(nodename)`

Comment: BTW, is `arr` really an array, or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `arr` is truly an array, just use `.forEach` or even better `.map` (with a shim on older browsers) to encapsulate each iteration's scope without the need for additional closures:

```
var xhrs = arr.map(function(e) {
    var nodename = e.hostname;
    var node_json = "/nodes/" + nodename;

    html +='<a href="'+node_json+'" target="_blank" id="host_'+nodename+'">data</a>';

    return $.ajax({
        url: node_json
    }).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#host_'+nodename).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
    });
});
```

The reason to use `var xhrs = arr.map()` instead of `.forEach` is that you then (for free) get the ability to call yet another callback once every AJAX request has completed:

```
$.when.apply($, xhrs).then(function() {
     // woot!  They all finished
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your are directly executing the method and passing its result as the callback for the `success` callback.

the `xhr` is already passed as the 3rd argument so try

```
success: function(nn,status, xhr) {
            $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
        }
```

---

if you have to pass the `nodename` as well, the you need to use a function that returns a function

```
success: (function(nn){
              return function(data ,status, xhr) {
                 // you can use nodename here...
                 $('#host_'+nn).append("last modified: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
            };
        })(nodename)
```

Comment: partly right, except that `nn` is his loop variable, not the AJAX result

Comment: @Alnitak, added a version for this case.

Comment: I already tried that before, but does't work. geíves huge errors, because the result data is in the error message

Comment: something with the whole response, I think, because now with the `(function...  )` it is not the correct syntax anymore with those prackets around. But I cannot test any further, cause the solution above worked.... Thanks for your help ;)