# File.lastModified is not supported by best browsers ? Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, html, last-modified

I have a file `js` that refresh every 5 minutes...
In my code (always in javascript) i have a `setInterval` that should check if the file is refresh.

I would to do it with

```
File.lastModified  
//OR
File.lastModifiedDate
```

But i read that isn't supported by all best browsers....is true?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModifiedDate#Browser_compatibility

Can you suggest me other alternatives ?

Thanks a lot and sorry fow my english....

Comment: This question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062132/get-the-modified-timestamp-of-a-file-with-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062132/get-the-modified-timestamp-of-a-file-with-javascript